# leaflet working localhost but not in hosting

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I am using the leaflet library https://leafletjs.com/ for the management of maps, in the localhost it works perfect but when I upload it to the hosting the map is not seen and in the console log it does not present any type of errors

Comment: Welcome to the site, Juan. You will need to provide more details (i.e. your code or a link to the published page) for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code, as i said it works perfectly on the localhost but when i upload it to the hosting it doesn't work and it doesn't show any error in the console log.

```
<pre>
    <link href="/lib/leaflet/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>

    <div id='mapid'></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            'use strict'
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (location) {
                var latlng = new L.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
                var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView(latlng, 13)
                L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
                    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                    maxZoom: 18,
                    tileSize: 512,
                    zoomOffset: -1,
                    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
                    accessToken: 'here I have my access token'
                }).addTo(mymap);

                var marker = L.marker(latlng, { draggable: 'true' }).addTo(mymap).on('drag', function (e) {
                    addPopup(marker);
                });

                addPopup(marker);

            });

        })

        function addPopup(marker) {

            var jsonQuery = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=" + marker.getLatLng().lat + "&lon=" + marker.getLatLng().lng + "&zoom=18&addressdetails=1";

            $.getJSON(jsonQuery).done(function (result_data) {
                var road;

                if (result_data.address.road) {
                    road = result_data.address.road;
                }
                else if (result_data.address.pedestrian) {
                    road = result_data.address.pedestrian;
                }
                else {
                    road = "No definido";
                }           
            });
        }
    </script>
    </pre>
```